# SVG clip path hole / inner cut

Tags: css, svg

```
<clipPath id="clip1">
    <rect x="10" y="222" height="30" width="50" rx="5"  />
</clipPath>

<image .... clip-path="url(#clip1)"  />
```

It cuts the outer space of the image. But I want to cut a hole into the image. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your purposes, you can use a mask

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<defs>
   <mask id="hole">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
   <rect x="50" y="50" height="50" width="100" rx="5"  fill="black" />
   </mask> 
  </defs> 
    <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"
 xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/200/200/any"
 mask="url(#hole)" >
  </image>  
    </svg>
```

Comment: I need transparent holes?!

Comment: @daniel Do you want to see through the hole in the image another background?

Comment: @daniel Changed the mask. So it is necessary?

Comment: @daniel Ask more questions about SVG. My favorite subject is animation. Always ready to help